# How do I count the number of objects a specific value from mutliple nested objects?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
var foodwebsites = {
  "bacon": [{
    "url": "stackoverflow.com",
  }],
  "icecream": [{
    "url": "example.com",
  }],
  "cheese": [{
    "url": "example.com",
  }]
}

var baconfoodwebsites = foodwebsites.bacon.filter(function(elem) {
  return elem.url == 'example.com';
}).length;

var icecreamfoodwebsites = foodwebsites.icecream.filter(function(elem) {
  return elem.url == 'example.com';
}).length;

var cheesefoodwebsites = foodwebsites.cheese.filter(function(elem) {
  return elem.url == 'example.com';
}).length;

var allfoodwebsites = baconfoodwebsites + icecreamfoodwebsites + cheesefoodwebsites;

console.log(baconfoodwebsites, icecreamfoodwebsites, cheesefoodwebsites, allfoodwebsites)
```

I'd like to do the exact same thing without the repetion of all these individual nested objects (bacon, icecream and cheese).

I assume the answer would be like:

```
var allfoodwebsites = foodwebsites=.filter(function( elem) {
    return elem.url == 'example.com';
}).length;
```

Additional Info:

I'd like to use only jQuery + Pure Javascript if possible.

I'd like to find all nested objects with `"url": "example.com"`

Comment: There was no JSON here. You have POJOs - Plain Old JavaScript Objects

Comment: Don't use a filter for counting.  You're creating an unnecessary array in memory.

Comment: Please clarify with the expected output, what you need to count? All available URLs? The number of URLs matching some pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Object.values, Array#reduce() & Array#flat() . Note flat() may need polyfill in some environments

```js
let foodwebsites = {"bacon": [{"url": "stackoverflow.com",}],"icecream": [{"url": "example.com",}],"cheese": [{"url": "example.com",}]};


const  getUrlCount = (url) => {
   return Object.values(foodwebsites)
       .flat()
       .reduce((a, {url:u})=> a + (url === u) , 0)

}

console.log(getUrlCount("example.com"))
```

Comment: `++a` ? why not just `a + 1` ? Or even `a + (url === u)` ?

Comment: @JonasWilms never been conditioned to use booleans like that. Simple shortcut

Answer (score 2):

The best option is the function `reduce` for counting approaches.

```js
let foodwebsites = {"bacon": [{"url": "stackoverflow.com",}],"icecream": [{"url": "example.com",}],"cheese": [{"url": "example.com",}]};
let allfoodwebsites = Object.values(foodwebsites).
          reduce((a, array) => a + array.
            reduce((a, {url}) => a + (url === "example.com"), 0), 0);

console.log(allfoodwebsites);
```

Answer (score 1):

### Solution:

You can create a function that will iterate the object keys and search for a `property` and `value` inside each accessed key's array of child objects:

```
let amount = (p, v, i = 0) => 
(Object.keys(foodwebsites).forEach(k => foodwebsites[k].forEach(o => o[p] === v && i++))
, i);
```

and it can be used like this:

```
amount("url", "example.com"); // 2
```

---

### Working Code Snippet:

```js
var foodwebsites = {
  "bacon": [{
    "url": "stackoverflow.com",
  }],
  "icecream": [{
    "url": "example.com",
  }],
  "cheese": [{
    "url": "example.com",
  }]
}

    let amount = (p, v, i = 0) => 
    (Object.keys(foodwebsites).forEach(k => foodwebsites[k].forEach(o => o[p] === v && i++))
    , i);

console.log(
  amount("url", "example.com")
);
//2
```

Comment: So would it be `let amount = amount("url", "example.com");` ?

Comment: @Tigerrrrr yes.

Answer (score 1):

I'd actually built one array of all these nested entries:

```
  const sites = Object.values(foodwebsites).flat();
```

Then you can easily iterate over it and count all the keys:

```
 const count = (arr, key, value) => arr.reduce((acc, it) => acc + it[key] === value, 0);

 console.log(
   count(sites, "url", "example.com"),
   count(sites, "url", "stackoverflow.com")
 );
```

Comment: @mplungjan on mobile.

Comment: @mplungjan you are right with the typo, but surely I can

Comment: My bad . Missed that the second time